# RxJS v5: How to make a POST request with params?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have some RxJS code and this is part of it:

```
.mergeMap(action => {
  const user = store.getState().user;
  return ajax.post(`${config.API_BASE_URL}/api/v1/rsvps`, {
    rsvp: {
      meetup_id: action.payload,
      user_id: user.id,
    }
  })
  .map(action => calendarActions.rsvpAdded(action.payload));
})
```

However, my server is telling me that the params are not in the right format:

```
[info] POST /api/v1/rsvps
[debug] Processing by ParrotApi.RsvpController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"rsvp" => "[object Object]"}
  Pipelines: [:api_auth]
[info] Sent 400 in 10ms
```

I tried using JSON.stringify but that didn't work. It just made my params a string.

```
rsvp: JSON.stringify({
  meetup_id: action.payload,
  user_id: 123,
})
```

`Parameters: %{"rsvp" => "{\"meetup_id\":1,\"user_id\":123}"}`

Comment: This question is probably related to what `ajax.post()` does/doesn't instead of RxJS.

Comment: it is imported from rxjs observable though: `import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know what parameter format is expected by your server but if you want to send JSON payload you should also include proper headers `Content-Type: application/json`. With RxJS 5 it's like the following:

```
ajax.post('url', {param: 42}, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
```

Now, the body payload is going to be automatically converted to JSON. (See [AjaxObservable.ts#L286](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts#L286).

Or if you don't want to send headers you'll need to convert the entire object to JSON yourself:

```
ajax.post('url', JSON.stringify({param: 42}));
```

By the way, you definitely don't want to combine these two methods (including the headers and calling `JSON.stringify` yourself) because this would convert the same payload to JSON twice.

Comment: `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` did the job! thanks so much